# Convert Tensorflow Tensor to Numpyarray

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, type-conversion, tensor

I have a `class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` as output and need to convert this to a numpy array.

.numpy() **doesn't work** because it isn't a **eagerTensor**.
.eval doesn't work as well, because i'm using **tensorflow >2.0**

Is there any other way to fix this?

```
img_height=330
img_width=600
img_depth=23

save_model="saved_Models/wheatModel"
prediction_data_path=["data/stacked/MOD13Q1.A2017.2738.tif","data/stacked/MOD13Q1.A2017.889.tif","data/stacked/MOD13Q1.A2017.923.tif"]

prediction_data=dataConv.preparePredictionData(prediction_data_path)

prediction_reshaped=dataConv.reshapeFiles(prediction_data,img_width,img_height,img_depth)

x_ds =tf.stack(prediction_reshaped)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(save_model)

model.predict(x_ds)

image=model.get_layer(name='prediction_image').output
n,output_width,output_height,output_depth,output_channels=image.shape
print(type(image))
image=tf.reshape(image,(output_width,output_height,output_depth))
print(type(image))

image.numpy()
```

So in the code above.

1. I load my trained model
2. predict the given images
3. get the output from the next to last layer
4. reshape this data
5. Now i want to convert this tensor to an numpyarray

Comment: It's better if you can add a code, but for me it looks like you are trying to see the value of the tensor while graph execution is not completed yet.

Comment: Try setting model.run_eagerly = True before using the model. This should run all calculations in eager mode and thus results in printable tensors.

Comment: unfortunately adding model.run_eagerly = True doesn't work for me. It still returns a normal tensor, not an eagerTensor. ..

Comment: odd tensorflow 2 supports the .numpy() command just fine and it should work for both eager tensor or variable tensor

Comment: `Eager execution` works nicely with `NumPy`. `NumPy` operations accept `tf.Tensor` arguments. The `tf.Tensor.numpy` method returns the object's value as a NumPy `ndarray`.Can you please share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!